# how can I turn column into rows in presto?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, presto, unpivot

I want to turn column into a new rows and save the values.

For example:

BEFORE

```
NAME  COMDEDY  HORROR  ROMANCE
brian    10     20     14
tom      20     10     11
```

AFTER

```
NAME    GANRE    RATING
brian   comedy     10
brian   horror     20
brian   romance    14
tom     comedy     20
tom     horror     10
tom     romance    11
```

I need to do this at least with python pandas ,if I can't do it with prestodb

Comment: Python pandas code is added as a solution !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it using presto sql:

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.genre, t2.rating
FROM table t1
CROSS JOIN unnest (
  array['comedy', 'horror', 'romance'],
  array[comedy, horror, romance]
) t2 (genre, rating)
```